# When running Chef, RubyGems throws a System Stack Error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, chef-infra

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3p392 and I've installed the latest chef gem (11.4.2). When I try to run any of the chef command line utilities, I get the following error:

`bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`

In fact, running the following also causes a similar error to be thrown:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'chef' # or gem 'chef', '11.4.2'
```

Digging a bit deeper, I see that the issue seems to originate from lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb:

`lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb:24: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`

Which is odd, because that line is apart of a block that's defining a hash of lambdas that represent various requirement operations (ie; are versions =, is version1 >= version2, etc).

```
class Gem::Requirement
  OPS = { #:nodoc:
    "="  =>  lambda { |v, r| v == r },
    "!=" =>  lambda { |v, r| v != r },
    ">"  =>  lambda { |v, r| v >  r },
    "<"  =>  lambda { |v, r| v <  r },
    ">=" =>  lambda { |v, r| v >= r }, # <-- line 24
    "<=" =>  lambda { |v, r| v <= r },
    "~>" =>  lambda { |v, r| v >= r && v.release < r.bump }
  }
  #...
end
```

Scrolling down the file, I see that the only place `OPS[">="]` could be called is on line 198:

```
  def satisfied_by? version
    raise ArgumentError, "Need a Gem::Version: #{version.inspect}" unless
      Gem::Version === version
    # #28965: syck has a bug with unquoted '=' YAML.loading as YAML::DefaultKey
    requirements.all? { |op, rv| (OPS[op] || OPS["="]).call version, rv } # <-- line 198
  end
```

I've noticed that at the time of running `requirements.all?`, requirements is set to `[[">=", #<Gem::Version "0">]]`. It seems to be evaluating `<Gem::Version "11.4.2"> >= <Gem::Version "0">`.

I've been working on this all day and I have yet to get to the bottom of it. Could anybody help me understand why RubyGems is throwing this error?

Thanks.

**edit**: Chef seems to run fine on 1.8.7. Could it be an issue with 1.9.3?

Comment: What happens if you write `gem 'chef', '11.4.2'`?

Comment: @RyanBigg Same thing, unfortunately.

Comment: It's working for me. What version of rubygems are you running? I'm on 1.8.24.

Comment: @EricR I upgraded everything on my system to match your versions, and everything is working. Try re-installing Ruby 1.9.3 perhaps?

Comment: @davogones I already have. No luck.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error with any versions of Chef. Is this still an issue?